# python setter setting two variables doesnt work for list

Tags: python, oop, getter-setter

i have a beginner question (my oop is terrible) about how to achieve a feature in python where i have an instance of a class (Line) where setting one attribute to a value automatically updates another attribute and vice versa.

I believe i did achieve that when my attributes are integers:

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        
        self.x0=0
        self.coordinates=0
 
    @property 
    def x0(self):
        return self._x0 
    
    @x0.setter
    def x0(self,x):
        self.coordinates=x
        self._x0=x 

if __name__=='__main__':
    l=Line()
    print(l.coordinates) # 0 
    l.x0=10
    print(l.coordinates) # 10  success !
```

However when i change coordinates variable to a list the same code fails:

```
class Line2:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        
        self.x0=0
        self.coordinates=[0,0]
 
    @property 
    def x0(self):
        return self._x0 
    
    @x0.setter
    def x0(self,x):
        self.coordinates[0]=x
        self._x0=x  

if __name__=='__main__':
    l2=Line2() # AttributeError: 'Line2' object has no attribute 'coordinates'   :( 
    print(l2.coordinates) # 0 
    l2.x0=10
    print(l2.coordinates) # 10
```

Could anyone point to me why this happens (it doesn't work for tuples as well) and also tell me if it's even possible to have a python class with a behavior like that (or how this behavior is called in oop etc etc)?

I  suspect i need to write a property and property.setter for coordinates variable for this to work, however i don't know how to write a setter updating specific item of a list.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**: In first case, you are just assigning the value without trying to read it, in second case with list, you are trying to read it with indexing while assigning the value of `coordinates` attribute which doesn't exist yet.

In the constructor when you are initializing variable `x0` it calls `setter` to basically set that value.
In first case, you are trying to assign a value to a variable without indexing i.e. `self.coordinates=x` it will not look for existing `coordinates` attribute, it will just create as if its a new attribute. However, `self.attribute` is actually undefined in first case too, you can check that trying to print it inside your setter before assigning the value:

```py
class Line:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.x0 = 0
        self.coordinates = 0
    @property
    def x0(self):
        return self._x0
    @x0.setter
    def x0(self, x):
        print(self.coordinates)
        self._x0 = x
        
l=Line()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 3, in __init__
  File "<input>", line 12, in x0
AttributeError: 'Line' object has no attribute 'coordinates'
```

In second case, you are basically trying to use indexing to assign the value to `self.coordinates` which basically doesn't exist. To overcome this, you need to first define `coordinates` attribute inside the constructor before setting value of `x0`

```py
class Line2:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.coordinates = [0, 0] #define this first
        self.x0 = 0
    @property
    def x0(self):
        return self._x0
    @x0.setter
    def x0(self, x):
        self.coordinates[0] = x
        self._x0 = x
if __name__ == '__main__':
    l2 = Line2()  
    print(l2.coordinates)  # 0 
    l2.x0 = 10
    print(l2.coordinates)  # 10 
 
#output   
[0, 0]
[10, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you ThePyGuy, could you tell me then why it worked in first example, when coordinates was an integer?

Comment: @pawelek69420 The answer has been updated